# Fullcalendar JS highlight the date that have event, click on that date will go to specific URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fullcalendar

In the official example, the event shows like this:

https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.5.0/demos/basic-views.html

It list every event in the calendar, and click on individual event will trigger the action.

However, I would like to customize a bit to :

Do not show any event, 
but highlight the date which has event, 
and click on that date go to the URL, e.g.

```
http://example.com/details?date=2017-09-10
```

Are there any option to change the layout like this? if not, then where to start the customize?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is possible. You can easily hide events using CSS. Then, using a little jQuery, you can set a color on the date square and a `data-url` to be used on click.

See comments in this starter snippet.
Have fun!

```js
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
  events:[
    {title:"Test",
     start:"2017-09-14",
     end:"2017-09-14"
    },
    {title:"Test",
     start:"2017-09-22",
     end:"2017-09-22"
    },
    {title:"Test",
     start:"2017-10-13",
     end:"2017-09-22"
    },
    {title:"Test",
     start:"2017-10-22",
     end:"2017-09-22"
    }
  ],
  eventAfterAllRender : function(view) {

    //Loop through all event to set the highlight and onclick url
    $(".fc-event-container").each(function(){

      // Get this day of the week number
      var weekDayIndex = $(this).index();
      // Get the calendar row
      var row = $(this).closest(".fc-row");
      // Get this date
      var date = row.find(".fc-day-top").eq(weekDayIndex).attr("data-date");
      // Add highlight and data-date
      row.find(".fc-day").eq(weekDayIndex)
        .addClass("highlight")
        .attr("data-url","example.com/details?date="+date);
    });
  }
});

// Click handler
$(document).on("click", ".highlight", function(){
  alert( $(this).data("url") );
});
```

```css
.fc-event-container{
  display:none;
}
.highlight{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.5.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: You loop through all the .fc-event-container classes each time an event is rendered, which seems a bit pointless. Would it not make more sense to use eventAfterAllRender https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/ for this, then the code only executes once? The only reason I could think not to is if you needed some data from the specific `calEvent`, and then you'd target `element` specifically. but you aren't using any values from it. Also, what's the reason for the timeout?

Comment: @ADyson: I didn't know about `eventAfterAllRender `... But I knew about the fact the code ran as much time as there is events in the month... But in that case, it wasn't an issue. Thanks to your comment, It is now a better answer. ;)